# How to have poetry automatically install packages before running a program?

Tags: python-poetry

I need to schedule the launch of Python programs that run inside a Poetry virtualenv. In practice, I use cron to schedule. Inside the crontab, I would put something like

```
poetry -C /home/user/project run python3 /home/user/project/program.py
```

However, the Poetry command `run` does not seem to install the packages. Apparently, I need to run `poetry -C /home/user/project install` first. This is not really convenient. For example, if the computer rebooted earlier, the Poetry installation is gone and the command inside cron fails.

I might put inside crontab something like

```
poetry -C /home/user/project install && poetry -C /home/user/project run python3 /home/user/project/program.py
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: Poetry is a development tool. It is not meant for use in production. -- Typically you would build the wheel distribution of the project, and then move on to other tools for the rest of the deployment into production.